# Autoplay video Youtube no funciona

Tags: html

Tengo un vídeo de youtube que no funciona si entro desde un celular. Este el el código que tengo, alguien sabe que esta mal ?

```
<iframe width="891" height="501" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b7dmg3jxZ88?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;mute=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=b7dmg3jxZ88" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Prueba de este modo: **`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b7dmg3jxZ88" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`**

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: A mí me está funcionando de este modo, prueba y comenta: **`<iframe id="yt-frame"
          width="891" height="501"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b7dmg3jxZ88?autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1"
          frameborder="0"
          ></iframe>`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es porque desde abril de 2018 Google cambió la política con respecto al *autoplay*  de sus vídeos de Youtube.

El caso es explicado con detalle en el artículo titulado:  **[*Autoplay Policy Changes* de François Beaufort](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)**, donde se explica, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

> La política de reproducción automática lanzada en [la versión] M66 estable
> bloquea efectivamente aproximadamente la
> mitad de las reproducciones de medios de audio y vídeo no deseadas en Chrome. Para Web
> Audio API, la política de reproducción automática se iniciará en [la versión] M70.
> Esto afecta a los juegos web, algunas aplicaciones WebRTC y otras
> páginas web que utilizan funciones de audio. Los desarrolladores
> deberán actualizar su código para aprovechar esta nueva política. Se pueden
> encontrar más detalles [en la sección API de Web Audio](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio)...
>
> ... Las políticas de reproducción automática de Chrome cambiarán en
> abril de 2018 y estoy aquí para decirte por qué y cómo esto afectará
> la reproducción de video con sonido...
>
> ### Nuevos comportamientos
>
> Como habrás notado, los navegadores web están adoptando políticas de
> reproducción automática más estrictas para mejorar la experiencia del
> usuario, minimizar los incentivos para instalar bloqueadores de
> anuncios y reducir el consumo de datos en redes caras y / o
> restringidas. Estos cambios están destinados a dar un mayor control de
> la reproducción a los usuarios y beneficiar a los editores en casos
> de uso legítimos.
>
> Las políticas de reproducción automática de Chrome son simples:
>
> - La reproducción automática silenciada siempre está permitida.
> - La reproducción automática con sonido está permitida si:
>
>   - El usuario ha interactuado con el dominio (ha hecho clic, toque, etc.).
>   - En el escritorio, se ha cruzado el umbral del [Índice de interacción con los medios del usuario (MEI)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei), lo que significa que
>     el usuario ya ha reproducido video con sonido.
>   - En dispositivos móviles, el usuario ha agregado el sitio a su pantalla de inicio. Los iframes superiores pueden [delegar permisos de
>     reproducción automática](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe) a sus iframes para permitir la
>     reproducción automática con sonido.

### Vías de solución

Leído lo anterior, podemos concluir que una vía de solución segura para activar el auto-play, es indicando que el sonido estará apagado (mute), agregando simplemente `mute=1` en el `src`:

(Puede que SO bloquee el auto-play aquí, pruébalo en tu dominio, a mi me funciona):

```html
<iframe id="yt-frame"
        width="891" height="501"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b7dmg3jxZ88?autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1">
</iframe>
```

Si quieres una reproducción automática con sonido, ten en cuenta que sólo será efectiva en los supuestos indicados más arriba.

Cualquier otra opción que no pase por el *mute*  activado será relativa, porque dependerá de los comportamientos del cliente.

Otra opción que podría ser más factible, sería hacerlo a través de la API de Youtube.