# ¿Cómo detener un loading al cargar un vídeo del listado de enlace?

Tags: jquery

En el listado de cargar páginas previo un loading funciona muy bien al tratarse de páginas web...

Pero al cargar un iframe de video `.mp4` el loading permanece siempre activo, no desaparece a diferencia de cargar un sitio web.

Por ejemplo al dar clic en el test5 que es la carga de un video, sigue quedando el pre-loading activo y no desaparece

Este es el código :) o en [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js6o94qv/)

```js
function ocultarLoad(){
 $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 var vid = $('#myvid');

 //default video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $("a.link:first").attr("href"));

    // addClass playing to first video link
    $("a.link:first").addClass("playing");


$("a.link").on("click" , function  (event) {

 // prevent link default
    event.preventDefault();
 $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    // change video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

    // remouve class playing from unplayed video href
    $(".vids a").removeClass("playing");

    // add class playing to video href
    $(this).addClass("playing");

    // add class paused to give the play/pause button the right look  
    $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
    
    
    // play the video
    vid[0].play();
   
});


//VIDEO EVENTS
    //video canplay event
    vid.on('canplay', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
    });
    
    //video waiting for more data event
    vid.on('waiting', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    });
//end
});
```

```css
.container * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container *:after , .container *:before {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A97A7A;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #010101;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 460px;
}
.vidcontainer {

 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 405px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.vids {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #292626;
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #616060;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #8A8A8A;
    border: 1px solid #AFACAC;

}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF8D00;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#fff;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:#ccc;
}


.vids a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*--- controllers ---*/
.controllers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
    border-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #ff8d00;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.paused:after {
    content: "\f04c";
}

.sound:after {
content: "\f027";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.sound2:after {
content: "\f028";
}

.muted:after {
    content: "\f026";
}
.btnFS:after {
     content: "\f065";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.ads {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #777;
    top: 27.5px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 11;
}
.bigplay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127.5px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}
.closeme {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    color: #ff8d00;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
 }
.playing:after {
    content: "\f01d";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff8d00;
    float: left;
}
/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #999;
}
.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.timeBar{
    z-index:10;
    width:0;
    background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar{
    z-index:5;
    width:0;
    background: #eee;
}
/* time and duration */
.time{
    width:12%;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:12px;
    right: -12%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}


.topControl:hover .progress {
    width: 88%;
    height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.volumeBar{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,141,0,0.5);
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
    top: 172.5px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}


ul.speedcnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
    background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="vidcontainer">
<iframe id="myvid" onload="ocultarLoad();" >

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  
</iframe>


<div class="loading">
 <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
    </div>

 <div class="videolist">
  <nav class="vids">
<a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">tsest9</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

---

**Nota:** Estoy usando Chrome la versión actual, el preloading solo desaparece en los sitios web y no en las multimedia como los vídeos.

Comment: ¿Qué navegadores pretendes soportar y a partir de que versiones?

Comment: En mi caso (usando Safari), el preloading desaparece de manera correcta, hice la prueba en todos los test y en todos desaparece el pre-loading. Quizá conviene que digas si has probado en otros navegadores y qué ocurre, no sea que el problema se deba o al navegador o a tu propio entorno local.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy usando Chrome la versión actual, el preloading solo desaparece en los sitios web y no en las multimedia como los vídeos

Comment: Lou me pregunto si [este no tendrá algo que ver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/195693/29967) también en tu caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Realmente esta basado en las API de youtube, pero me es útil tenerlo en cuenta para evitar tener futuros problemas, gracias :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Problemas de diseño

Primero que nada, hay unos pocos errores de diseño. Hay que eliminar la función `ocultarLoad`, porque no es necesario, ya que el `fadeout` está en `vid.on`.

```
function ocultarLoad(){
    $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
}
```

En consecuencia, eliminarlo en la etiqueta `iframe`.

```
<iframe id="myvid" onload="ocultarLoad();" >
```

Queda así:

```
<iframe id="myvid" >
```

Además hay que eliminar esta línea, que tira error. El video se reproduce automáticamente al cargar el `iframe`, por lo que no tiene sentido agregarlo.

```
vid[0].play();
```

También quitar la clase `.btnPlay`, ya que no existe ningún botón que tenga esa clase.

Quitarlo desde el *CSS*

```
.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

También desde el *JavaScript*:

```
// add class paused to give the play/pause button the right look  
$('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
```

## Problema principal

Una vez resueltos estos problemas de diseño, hay que tener en cuenta una cosa:

El *jQuery* espera **poder reproducir** *(can play)* el video, cuando es una página *HTML*. El atributo es solo compatible con `<audio>` y `<video>`, pero no con un `<iframe>`.

Si es un video, hay que usar `canplay` , de lo contrario hay que usar `load`.

Como *jQuery* no puede entrar en el contenido de un `iframe`, no es posible detectar si lo que hay dentro es un video o una página. Entonces, si la *URL* termina en `.mp4`, podemos crear un `<video>`, de lo contrario, creamos un `<iframe>`, entonces hago un *RegExp* `^.+\.mp4$`.

Dentro de `<video>` se le agrega un `<source>` con el atributo `src`, que es la *URL*, y `type`, que en este caso es `video/mp4`.

Para ordenar mejor las cosas, hice una función llamada `insertar_contenido`, que dependiendo de la *URL*, hace alguna de las dos cosas, o insertar un `video`, o un `iframe`. También encapsulé las funciones del `fadeIn` y `fadeOut`, ahora son llamadas `mostrar` y `ocultar`.

En algunas ocasiones, la extensión puede no coincidir con el formato del video, puede terminar en `.mp4`, y al final tener diferentes códecs `ogv` o `mpeg H264`. Para esto, al `type` se le puede asignar `video/mp4; codecs=avc1`, pero hay que saberlo de antemano.

Para saber el códec es necesario descargar el video y abrirlo con un programa que pueda leer el codec, puede ser un reproductor de videos. Por ejemplo, el *VLC* puede verlo solo mientras lo está reproduciendo, en *Tools -> Información del códec*.

## Código

En los únicos casos donde puede fallar es cuando la página a cargar no existe o el navegador no puede cargarlo en el `iframe`, o que puede cargarlo pero no lo carga por seguridad. Es recomendable no mezclar contenido *HTTP* en páginas *HTTPS*. En lo posible siempre usar *HTTPS*, que es contenido seguro certificado en *SSL*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){
  var contenido,fuente
  var url = elemento.attr("href")
  var ext = "mp4"
  var formato = ext
  var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\."+ext+"$").test(url)
  var cargando = $('.loading')
  function mostrar(){cargando.fadeIn(200)}
  function ocultar(){cargando.fadeOut(100)}
  mostrar()
  if(es_video){
   contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
   fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
   fuente.attr("src",url)
   fuente.attr("type","video/"+formato)
   contenido.attr("controls",true)
   contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
   contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
   contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
   contenido.append(fuente)
  }else{
   contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
   contenido.attr("src",url)
   contenido.on('load', ocultar)
  }
  vid.html("")
  vid.append(contenido)
  $(".vids a").removeClass("playing")
  elemento.addClass("playing")
 }

 var vid = $('#myvid')
 var primer_elemento = $("a.link:first")

 insertar_contenido(vid,primer_elemento)
 primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

 $("a.link").on("click" , function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  insertar_contenido(vid,esto)
 })
})
```

```css
.container * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container *:after , .container *:before {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A97A7A;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #010101;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 460px;
}
.vidcontainer {

 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 405px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.videolist {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.vids {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #292626;
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #616060;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #8A8A8A;
    border: 1px solid #AFACAC;

}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF8D00;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#fff;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.vids a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*--- controllers ---*/
.controllers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.controllers button {
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.controllers button:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
    border-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #ff8d00;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
}
.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.paused:after {
    content: "\f04c";
}
.sound:after {
content: "\f027";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.sound2:after {
content: "\f028";
}
.muted:after {
    content: "\f026";
}
.btnFS:after {
     content: "\f065";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.ads {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #777;
    top: 27.5px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 11;
}
.bigplay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127.5px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}
.closeme {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    color: #ff8d00;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
 }
.playing:after {
    content: "\f01d";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff8d00;
    float: left;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
.topControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Progress bar */
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #999;
}
.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.timeBar{
    z-index:10;
    width:0;
    background: #ff8d00;
}
.bufferBar{
    z-index:5;
    width:0;
    background: #eee;
}

/* time and duration */
.time{
    width:12%;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:12px;
    right: -12%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.topControl:hover .time {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.topControl:hover .progress {
    width: 88%;
    height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.volumeBar{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    z-index: 10;
}
.loading {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,141,0,0.5);
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
    top: 172.5px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}
ul.speedcnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
}
ul.speedcnt li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.speedcnt li.selected {
    background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vidcontainer">
    <div id="myvid"></div>
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="videolist">
    <nav class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">tsest9</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí es posible acceder al documento de un frame/iframe por medio de `documentElement`; la única restricción es que **ambas deben estar bajo un mismo dominio**.

Comment: @gugadev Entiendo. De todos modos, este no es el caso.

Comment: Veo que no es el caso, solo puse la observación. Btw, no se entiende qué propósito tiene poner un vídeo en un iframe en lugar **de la etiqueta apropiada** para esto; es decir, `video` y `source`. + @Lou.

Comment: @gugadev Es cierto, lo había hecho sin `source`, solo con el `src`. Edité la respuesta. Ahora la expresión regular extrae la extensión de la _URL_ desde una variable, así es reutilizable en `type`.

Comment: Hola @ArtEze disculpa por de nuevo molestarte, tengo abierta una pregunta basada al código que muy agradecida me has proporcionado, será posible cuando dispongas de tiempo, poder ayudarme en esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238593/cómo-enviar-contenedor-de-texto-desde-un-listado-a-otro-contenedor-usando-jquer y a su vez si no es mucho pedir, explicarme qué consideraciones tener en cuenta a un futuro si deseo agregar otras peticiones al código... Por favor ayúdame sí, plis :(

Answer (score 3):

Antes que nada hay que resaltar que dicho «problema» ocurre en Chrome principalmente, en Firefox y Edge funciona «bien» (se oculta el loading una vez carga el archivo), y en Safari 12 parece funcionar de forma intermitente según las pruebas que hice.

---

El mensaje que aparece en la consola al cargar los videos en Chrome es:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4".

Lo cual traduce aproximadamente:

> Recurso interpretado como documento, pero transferido con MIME de tipo video/mp4...

En otras palabras, Chrome esperaba un documento (HTML probablemente) pero le entregamos un video.

---

**El problema parece estar en que Chrome no lanza ningún evento en un iframe cuando su contenido no es un documento HTML.** Esto significa en nuestro caso que el evento onLoad nunca es lanzado y nunca se oculta el div que contiene el *loading*.

Este parece ser el típico problema que no es un *bug* sino un *feature* de Chrome lo que estamos analizando.

---

Como casi siempre, hay varias formas de solucionar este problema, una consiste en agregar en el *handler* de clic que ya tienes, un código de JavaScript que detecte que estás en Chrome (y en Safari tal vez en caso que sea relevante), y revisar después de X tiempo si hay algo de contenido en el iframe (con lo cual asumiríamos que la carga del video fue exitosa) y ocultar el *loading*:

```
setTimeout(function() {

  if ($('#mivid').contents().find('*') != 'undefined') {
    $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
  }

},1000);
```

Comment: Invito (de nuevo) a quien votó negativo a que explique el motivo y además a que publique una mejor solución, seguramente hay mucho mejores que esta.

Comment: Gracias por la información ayuda mucho para tener en cuenta los problemas que se enfrenta mi código a diferentes navegadores, no he probado el código, en la noche realizó las pruebas :) +1