# ¿Cómo enviar contenedor de texto desde un listado a otro contenedor usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Mediante un gran aporte, por parte de [@ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232160/c%C3%B3mo-detener-un-loading-al-cargar-un-v%C3%ADdeo-del-listado-de-enlace) tengo un listado donde puedo enviar y recibir datos en etiquetas especificas sin recargar la página ejemplo, si en el listado es un enlace de vídeo, ese vídeo se enviara y se reproducirá en una etiqueta `<video></video>`, si es un sitio web, se ejecutara en una etiqueta `<iframe>`, cada información en sus respectiva etiquetas.

Se puede comprobar en el siguiente código completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){
  var contenido,fuente
  var url = elemento.attr("href")
  var ext = "mp4"
  var formato = ext
  var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\."+ext+"$").test(url)
  var cargando = $('.loading')
  function mostrar(){cargando.fadeIn(200)}
  function ocultar(){cargando.fadeOut(100)}
  mostrar()
  if(es_video){
   contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
   fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
   fuente.attr("src",url)
   fuente.attr("type","video/"+formato)
   contenido.attr("controls",true)
   contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
   contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
   contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
   contenido.append(fuente)
  }else{
   contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
   contenido.attr("src",url)
   contenido.on('load', ocultar)
  }
  vid.html("")
  vid.append(contenido)
  $(".vids a").removeClass("playing")
  elemento.addClass("playing")
 }

 var vid = $('#myvid')
 var primer_elemento = $("a.link:first")

 insertar_contenido(vid,primer_elemento)
 primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

 $("a.link").on("click" , function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  insertar_contenido(vid,esto)
 })
})
```

```css
.container * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container *:after , .container *:before {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A97A7A;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #010101;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 460px;
}
.vidcontainer {

 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 405px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.videolist {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.vids {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #292626;
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #616060;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #8A8A8A;
    border: 1px solid #AFACAC;

}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF8D00;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#fff;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.vids a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*--- controllers ---*/
.controllers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.controllers button {
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.controllers button:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
    border-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #ff8d00;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
}
.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.paused:after {
    content: "\f04c";
}
.sound:after {
content: "\f027";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.sound2:after {
content: "\f028";
}
.muted:after {
    content: "\f026";
}
.btnFS:after {
     content: "\f065";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.ads {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #777;
    top: 27.5px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 11;
}
.bigplay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127.5px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}
.closeme {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    color: #ff8d00;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
 }
.playing:after {
    content: "\f01d";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff8d00;
    float: left;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
.topControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Progress bar */
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #999;
}
.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.timeBar{
    z-index:10;
    width:0;
    background: #ff8d00;
}
.bufferBar{
    z-index:5;
    width:0;
    background: #eee;
}

/* time and duration */
.time{
    width:12%;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:12px;
    right: -12%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.topControl:hover .time {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.topControl:hover .progress {
    width: 88%;
    height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.volumeBar{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    z-index: 10;
}
.loading {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,141,0,0.5);
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
    top: 172.5px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}
ul.speedcnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
}
ul.speedcnt li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.speedcnt li.selected {
    background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vidcontainer">
    <div id="myvid"></div>
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="videolist">
    <nav class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">tsest9</a>
      <a class="link" href="#">tsest10</a>
      <div class="text-data"><span>Contenido e información del enlace test10</span></div>
      <a class="link" href="#">tsest11</a>
      <div class="text-data"><span>Contenido e información del enlace test11</span></div>
      <a class="link" href="#">tsest12</a>
      <div class="text-data"><span>Contenido e información del enlace test12</span></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me he visto en la necesidad de también poder trasportar toda la información que contenga este div `<div class="text-data"></div>`, su texto e incluso sus etiquetas, imágenes todo lo que contenga ese div, esa información traspasarla al cuadro del diseño al dar click en el enlace **tses10**.

Había pensado, que siguiendo el mismo patrón o el mismo funcionamiento del código jQuery traspasar al texto cuando en el `href="#"` exista el símbolo numeral `#`.

Investigando un poco encontré  esté código

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#lorem").html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

**¿Pero como lo puedo adaptar al código jQuery?** Sobre todo el problema persiste porque en el código jQuery ya existe patrones u funcionalidades que permite poder ejecutar información según lo que este enlazado, como los sitios web en los `<iframe>`, los vídeos en las etiquetas `<video>`.

Comment: Me perdí un poco leyendo la pregunta. ¿Quieres pasar un `div` entero de un sitio a otro según he entendido. Si es tan simple como eso, no sé por qué te detienes en tantos detalles. ¿O es que no es eso lo que quieres? Simplemente, si quieres pasar un `div` a otro sitio, lo que más interesa es saber la forma de identificar ese `div` para transportarlo. ¿Tiene un `id`, tiene una posición exacta en un contenedor, tiene una clase, tiene algo que lo identifique?

Comment: @A.Cedano El enlace encargado de transportar el div a otro sitio `<a class="link" href="#">test10</a>` y debajo del enlace el div que debe ser transportado
   `<div class="text-data display-none">Contenido e información del enlace test10</div>` claro que ese div debe estar con un `display:none;` una vez que se trasporte quitarle el `display:none`

Comment: Que me pierdo con tus explicaciones. Entendí hasta aquí: *quiero pasar un div a otro sitio, toda esta información va estar en el listado de los enlaces que se encuentran en: <div class="videolist"> <nav> <a>*  ... ¿que quieres poner el `div`  a partir de ese `nav`?  Es que lo otro que empiezas a explicar no creo que sirva de nada (para el caso). O sea, si transportas un  `div` a una parte se aplicarán las reglas o acciones que hayas definido para los elementos en ese contenedor o si le otorgas una clase, un id o lo que sea, se aplicarán las reglas que hayas decidido para ese id, clase, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si es exactamente lo que usted me indica, perdón :( por no ser claro, trate de explicar de como funciona el código para que pueda familiarizarse con el código

Comment: Al hacer `vid.append(contenido)` lo que se hace es **mover una etiqueta (`contenido` que es creado mediante _JavaScript_) hacia otra etiqueta (`vid`)**, ¿Cómo surgió tu problema? ¿Con qué objetivo? En verdad no entendí casi nada.

Comment: Mi pregunta en verdad es, ¿Qué es exactamente lo que se intenta hacer?

Comment: @ArtEze Alguna vez has visto algún curso en la plataforma de Udemy, en su listado de cursos en ocasiones no existe vídeo si no solo texto, bueno ese texto se muestra en el mismo cuadro donde se reproducen los vídeos, solo que en vez de mostrar el vídeo muestra el texto, con sus estilos agregados al texto etc.

Comment: @Lou Sugiero que hagas tu propio archivo html, de manera que al tocar en un ejemplo cargue el `iframe` con ese contenido. Pero ahora entiendo lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: @ArtEze Si lo he realizado de esta forma, pero me gustaría que el tema del `iframe` quede para sitios externos, y para cosas internas que son llamadas desde la base de datos, poder traspasar esa información al dar click en unos de los indexes al cuadro del diseño, sobre todo para cuando cree el panel de administración, y de acceso a otras personas que será fácil solo agregar texto con diseños, en el caso de mi persona podría crear esa información en archivos html distintos, pero y esos usuarios como,

Comment: @ArtEze si no saben de programación solo administración de contenido mediante un panel fácil de manejar.

Comment: @ArtEze Para que sea más claro, puedes ejecutar el código, al final del listado se encuentra los enlaces **tsest10, tsest11, tsest12** debajo de esos enlaces existen unos div, con información, esos div en el listado deben estar oculto mediante un `display:none` al momento de hacer click en esos enlaces traspasar la información de ese div, al cuadro del diseño.

Comment: Esta pregunta me mareo de principio a fin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi solución es crear un `div` nuevo, que contiene todos los contenidos ocultos, en mi caso lo llamo `ocultado` y le agrego la propiedad `style="display: none"` para que no se vea. Dentro, agrego los contenidos.

Dentro están los `div` con los contenidos, y le agrego una clase propia para que pueda ser identificado por *jQuery*, `class="cuadro"`. Además, le agrego un `id`, por ejemplo, `id="c_link_12"`.

```
<div id="ocultado" style="display: none">
  <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_10" >Contenido e información del enlace test10</div>
  <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_11" >Contenido e información del enlace test11</div>
  <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_12" >Contenido e información del enlace test12</div>
</div>
```

Los enlaces con contenido de la propia página, tienen que tener el `id` coincidiendo con el `id` del `cuadro`.

```
<a class="link" href="#" id="link_10" >test10</a>
<a class="link" href="#" id="link_11" >test11</a>
<a class="link" href="#" id="link_12" >test12</a>
```

La diferencia es que al `id` del `cuadro` se le agrega `c_` al principio, para que puedan ser identificados correctamente.

En el código *jQuery* se hace una comprobación, si el `id` es `undefined`, inserta un `iframe`, de lo contrario muestra el contenido *HTML* propio.

```
var id = elemento.attr("id")
if(id==undefined)
{
    contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
    contenido.attr("src",url)
    contenido.on('load', ocultar)       
}else{
    contenido = $(document.createElement("div"))
    contenido.append($("#c_"+id))
    ocultar()
}
```

Lo que hago con el código es, simplemente mover el `div` que estaba en `ocultado` *al cuadro de diseño*. En este caso, al mover un `div` no hay `onload`, porque ya estaba cargado, entonces, simplemente llamo a la función para desaparecer el *loading*.

Si anteriormente había un contenido, lo muevo a `ocultado`, es decir, voy moviendo los `div` a donde correspondan.

```
var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
if(cuadro.length!=0){
    $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
}
```

El método `find` es el equivalente de `querySelectorAll` de *JavaScript* pero para *jQuery*. Si existe el elemento con `class = "cuadro"`, lo mueve al ocultado.

Código completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){
  
  var contenido,fuente
  var url = elemento.attr("href")
  var ext = "mp4"
  var formato = ext
  var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\."+ext+"$").test(url)
  var cargando = $('.loading')
  function mostrar(){cargando.fadeIn(200)}
  function ocultar(){cargando.fadeOut(100)}
  mostrar()
  var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
  if(cuadro.length!=0){
   $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
  }
  if(es_video){
   contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
   fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
   fuente.attr("src",url)
   fuente.attr("type","video/"+formato)
   contenido.attr("controls",true)
   contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
   contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
   contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
   contenido.append(fuente)
  }else{
   var id = elemento.attr("id")
   if(id==undefined)
   {
    contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
    contenido.attr("src",url)
    contenido.on('load', ocultar)  
   }else{
    contenido = $(document.createElement("div"))
    contenido.append($("#c_"+id))
    ocultar()
   }
  }
  vid.html("")
  vid.append(contenido)
  $(".vids a").removeClass("playing")
  elemento.addClass("playing")
 }

 var vid = $('#myvid')
 var primer_elemento = $("a.link:first")

 insertar_contenido(vid,primer_elemento)
 primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

 $("a.link").on("click" , function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  insertar_contenido(vid,esto)
 })
})
```

```css
#myvid {
  color: #ffff;
}

.container * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 -o-transition: 0.5s;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.container *::after , .container *::before {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'tahoma';
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2em;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #A97A7A;
}

.container {
 width: 960px;
 background: #010101;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 height: 460px;
}

.vidcontainer {
 width: 75%;
 height: 100%;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 405px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
 float: right;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.vids {
 margin: 5px;
 background-color: #292626;
 max-height: 450px;
 min-height: 450px;
 border: 1px solid #616060;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 list-style: none;
 direction: rtl;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 5px;
 background-color: #8A8A8A;
 border: 1px solid #AFACAC;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: #FF8D00;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background-color: #fff;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.vids a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
 padding: 8px 5px;
 margin: 5px;
}

/* --- controllers --- */
.controllers {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
 border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #777;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
 border-color: #ff8d00;
 color: #ff8d00;
 background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay::after {
 content: "\f04b";
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.paused::after {
 content: "\f04c";
}

.sound::after {
 content: "\f027";
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.sound2:after {
 content: "\f028";
}

.muted::after {
 content: "\f026";
}

.btnFS::after {
 content: "\f065";
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.ads {
 height: 350px;
 width: 350px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #777;
 top: 27.5px;
 right: 40px;
 z-index: 11;
}

.bigplay {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 127.5px;
 left: 85px;
 z-index: 11;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 150px;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}

.closeme {
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 background-color: #fff;
 top: -10px;
 right: -10px;
 border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px!important;
 color: #ff8d00;
 font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
 background-color: #999;
 border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
 -webkit-transition: 0s;
 -o-transition: 0s;
 transition: 0s;
}

.playing:after {
 content: "\f01d";
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 color: #ff8d00;
 float: left;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
.topControl {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 50px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 1;
}

/* Progress bar */
.progress {
 width: 100%;
 height: 5px;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #999;
}

.progress span {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
}

.timeBar{
 z-index:10;
 width:0;
 background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar{
 z-index:5;
 width:0;
 background: #eee;
}

/* time and duration */
.time{
 width:12%;
 float:right;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:12px;
 right: -12%;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
 right: 0;
 opacity: 1;
}

.topControl:hover .progress {
 width: 88%;
 height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 70px;
 height: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 background-color: #999;
}

.volumeBar{
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #ff8d00;
 z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.5);
 height: 405px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}

i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
 font-size: 60px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
 top: 172.5px;
 left: 330px;
 position: absolute;
}

.disabled {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: not-allowed;
 background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}

ul.speedcnt {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 60px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 list-style: none;
 -webkit-transition: 0s;
 -o-transition: 0s;
 transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
 background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vidcontainer">
    <div id="myvid"></div>
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="videolist">
    <nav class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">test9</a>
      <a class="link" href="#" id="link_10" >test10</a>
      <a class="link" href="#" id="link_11" >test11</a>
      <a class="link" href="#" id="link_12" >test12</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none">
      <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_10" >Contenido e información del enlace test10</div>
      <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_11" >Contenido e información del enlace test11</div>
      <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_12" >Contenido e información del enlace test12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, eres fantástico tomare algún curso muy avanzado sobre jQuery, para no causar mucha molestia aquí :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta @ArtEze las preguntas interesantes tienen su valor iniciativa de iniciar recompensa cómo está y cómo mucha más que aporta para el actor de la pregunta y claro está para los lectores. Me gustó el ejemplo de **Lou** por ese inicié la recompensa como algunos otras preguntas en tiempo atrás. Puedes construir una modificación para mí, no exactamente aquí ya la respuesta está aceptada por parte de **Lou** sino aquí https://jsfiddle.net/p2bx6q7e/ podrías agregar dos links más uno para atrás y otro en siguiente para que al dar clic en dicha acción ya sea en siguiente

Comment: Siga al siguiente link del listado y así sucesivamente y si se da clic en la acción atrás retroceder en el listado de enlaces. Un + 1 adicional por el gran ejemplo que desarrollaste.

Comment: @Fernando Lo dejo aquí definitivamente. Los enlaces atrás y siguiente aparecen en un `nav` separado: https://jsfiddle.net/ArtEze/sgy4tah5/109/

Comment: @ArtEze Excelente, en unas de sus anteriores pregunta de **Lou** basadas a este tema, cuando dabas clic en unos de esos listado agregaba un icono play para así indentificar en que enlace del listado se encuentra, le han eliminado está funcionalidad?  O aún existe está funcionalidad en el código, puedes agregarle esa funcionalidad que ya tenía en su primer pregunta sobre este tema gracias por el aporte. Saludos.

Comment: @Fernando Era un problema del CSS, al responder la pregunta había quitado varias partes para entenderlo mejor yo. Aquí dejo la solución, tuve que cambiar una parte también en _HTML_, _jQuery_ y _CSS_ para identificar el `nav`, ahora tiene el `id` `#enlaces` https://jsfiddle.net/ArtEze/sgy4tah5/144/

Comment: @ArtEze Amigo, disculpe que te moleste sera que tienes un poquito de tiempo en ayudarme en una pregunta basada a este mismo código, la pregunta es la siguiente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295514/cómo-agregar-el-tipo-del-formato-del-vídeo-según-la-extensión-con-jquery por favor

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo donde se mueve un `div` completo (alcanzado por su `id`)  de un sitio a otro. El `div` tiene dentro texto y tiene una imagen. Esa imagen tiene un *listener*. Al mover el `div` de un sitio a otro, las propiedades de los elementos no se pierden (en este caso el *listener*  de la imagen sigue funcionando).

```js
var btnMover = document.getElementById('btnMover');
var imgSO = document.getElementById('imgSO');


btnMover.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var divAMover=document.getElementById('a-mover');
  fragment.appendChild(divAMover);
  document.getElementById('destino').appendChild(fragment);
  divAMover.classList.remove('oculto');
});

imgSO.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log("Siempre escuchando");
});
```

```css
#general {
  background-color: orange;
}

#destino {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.oculto {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <div id="no-mover">
    <p>Esto no se moverá</p>
  </div>
  <div id="a-mover" class="oculto">
    <p>Esto se moverá, imagen incluida. Haz clic en la imagen antes y después de mover y verás...</p>
    <a title="Stack Exchange [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons" href="#"><img id="imgSO" width="128" alt="Stack Overflow logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png/128px-Stack_Overflow_logo.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<button id="btnMover">Mover</button>
<div id="destino">
  <p>Te estoy esperando...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Es un ejemplo claro, pero el div que se va a pasar a otro sitio debe estar oculto, una vez que ya se pase ahí se debe mostrar el contenido.

Comment: @Lou revisa ahora el código editado. Sólo se muestra al moverlo.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, tarde analizaré el ejemplo que me has proporcionado para ver si lo puedo adaptar al código jQuery.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tengo una curiosidad, si desea agregar más listado de información a pasar, esto generaría más líneas de código javascript o bastaría con la existente.

Comment: @Lou jQuery es una librería Javascript y esto es Javascript puro. O sea este código funcionará en tu navegador y será más rápido.

Comment: @IniDesign.com eso depende de lo que haya que hacer y cómo. Y de la forma en que se organicen los elementos, sabiendo que se pueden agrupar elementos por clase por ejemplo con un solo click puedes traer a un div elementos que estén en varios sitios.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es pasar el contenido de un div a otro hay una solucion simple sin mucho codigo, usando `clone()` el cual nos permite copiar todos los nodos del DOM, no perderias funcionalidades.

Encierras todo lo que deseas clonar en un div con su id y creas el otro div que es donde vas a clonar la info y añades una funcion en algun boton por ejemplo, hariamos algo asi:

HTML + JS

```
   <div id="contenedor-1">
     <h1>Div con la informacion</h1>
     <p>aqui esta todo</p>
   </div>
   <!-- boton con la funcion -->
   <input type="button" id="clonar" value="clonar div">

   <div id="contenedor-2"></div>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // toma el id del boton y habilita un solo click
        $("#clonar").one("click", function(){

            $("#contenedor-1").clone().appendTo("#contenedor-2");
            alert('Duplicado exitosamente');

        });
    });
 </script>
```

Es importante el hecho de que la función se ejecute con un solo click ya que sino se hace entonces va a clonar los elementos las veces que se clickee en el botón, aunque esto se podría arreglar con unas lineas extras en js. Aquí tienes otra idea.