# ¿Cómo agregar el tipo del formato del vídeo según la extensión con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Mi código funciona de manera predeterminada solo con el formato de archivo `MP4`

> **Nota:** Mi código esta adaptado para trabajar con el `plugin` `player video.js`

```
function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){
    var contenido, fuente
    var url = elemento.attr("href")
    var ext = "mp4"
    var formato = ext
    var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\."+ext+"$").test(url)
    var cargando = $('.loading')
    function mostrar(){cargando.fadeIn(200)}
    function ocultar(){cargando.fadeOut(100)}
    mostrar()
    var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
    if(cuadro.length!=0){
        $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
    }
    if(es_video){
        var json = {"controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto", "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2]};
        contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
        fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
        fuente.attr("src",url)


        fuente.attr("type","video/"+formato)


        contenido.attr("class","video-js vjs-default-skin")
        contenido.attr('data-setup', JSON.stringify(json));
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

Necesito poder usar otros tipos de formatos como: `mp3`, `mp4`, `m3u8`, `ts`, `video YouTube` entre otros.

Entonces, de acuerdo con la extensión del archivo, agregue el formato de tipo de vídeo, por ejemplo:

```
if(var ==="mp4"){
     fuente.attr("type","video/mp4")
}elseif(var === "m3u8"){
     fuente.attr("type","application/x-mpegURL")
}
```

Tengo la siguiente idea, no sé si es correcto y, creo que no porque no da resultados:

```
function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){
    var ext = "mp4, mp3, mpeg, m3u8" //Entre otros
}

if(es_video){

    if(var ==="mp4"){
         fuente.attr("type","video/mp4")
    }elseif(var === "m3u8"){
         fuente.attr("type","application/x-mpegURL")
    }
}
```

Tal vez si hubiera sido en `PHP` habría tenido éxito.

Sé muy poco sobre `JavaScript / jQuery`, ¿Me podrían explicar cómo lograr este objetivo, por favor?

Comment: Hola, no comprendo bien tu duda. En todo caso, si deseas obtener el tipo de medio (Mime Type) de algún recurso o archivo, podrías usar una librería. He usado con mucho éxito [`mime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime), creo que podrías probar con eso y tal vez te simplifique las cosas. Si no es lo que buscas, me disculpas por no haberte entendido. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola, gracias por la recomendación, pero no es lo que buscó. Ya tengo funcionando correctamente mi aplicación... Y, mi código está vinculado adaptado a Video.JS empezar por algo nuevo es medio complicado... Mi código hace exactamente lo mismo, solamente necesito es poder agregar más extensiones de formato a: `var ext = "mp4"`  y mendiante un `if` agregar el tipo de formato de aplicación algo similar como PHP debe tener `jQuery`  ejemplo:

Comment: `if(ext==="ts" || ext==="m3u8"){
            echo 'type="application/x-mpegURL">';
        }elseif(ext==="mp4"){
            echo 'type="video/mp4">';
        }elseif(ext==="mp3"){
            echo 'type="audio/mp3">';
        }`

Comment: Se me ocurre que crees un objeto javascript: `{"clave": "valor"}`. Cada clave será una extensión y el valor será el tipo `mime`. Por ejemplo: `{"mp4": "video/mp4", "m3u8": "application/xmpegURL", ... }`. Luego para acceder al mismo haces: `let mimeType = obj[ext];` si `ext` es una de la extensiones listadas en tu objeto, entonces `mimeType` tendrá el valor correspondiente, y si por el contrario `ext` no forma parte de las extensiones de tu objeto, entonces `mimeType` será `undefined`. Y ya por allí tienes una forma de decidir. Te evitas todos los `if else`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Entendí la parte de los objetos... Ya en la otra no comprendo muy bien, voy a ver qué tal me va. Gracias ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer una función que mediante la *URL* extraiga la extensión y la analice determinando su tipo *MIME*, `tipo/extensión`, la primera parte es el tipo, que puede ser `audio`, `video` y la segunda, la extensión. Algunas veces la extensión queda igual, como por ejemplo, `mp3`, `mp4`, pero otras, puede cambiar, por ejemplo para `m3u8` queda `x-mpegURL`.

Para extraer la extensión, una manera es usando una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```
var regex_ext = url.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+/gi)
```

Esto, lo que hace es capturar todas las coincidencias que tengan un punto (`.`), y luego del punto, números o letras del abecedario. Ejemplo, en `audio.mp3?2` coincide con `.mp3?2`, pero como `?2` no es parte del abecedario, solo captura `.mp3` y se guarda en la variable `ext` para poder comprobar si es tal extensión.

Si existe alguna coincidencia, se busca la última coincidencia, es decir, la que está más a la derecha, y luego se le quita el punto mediante `slice(1)`.

```
if(regex_ext){
    ext = regex_ext.slice(-1)[0].slice(1)
    ...
```

Mediante expresiones regulares, también se puede comprobar si coincide la extensión. En el siguiente caso, coincide con `mp3` o `mpeg`, y determina que es un audio.

```
if( /^(mp3|mpeg)$/i.test(ext) ){ tipo = "audio" }
```

Lo siguiente es una comprobación sin usar expresiones regulares, se hace esto para casos específicos en donde el tipo y la extensión varían totalmente:

```
if( ext=="m3u" ){ tipo = "audio"; ext = "mpegURL" }
```

Para determinar que es un enlace de *Youtube*, se puede improvisar una expresión regular, que mira si tiene un código especial al final. El código del video son 11 caracteres, que pueden ser números del 0 al 9, letras del abecedario sin la ñ, el guión y el guión bajo, `[0-9a-z-_]{11}`, es base 64 porque son 10 números, 26 minúsculas, 26 mayúsculas, 1 guión y 1 guión bajo. Sumando eso, `10 + 26 + 26 + 1 + 1` queda 64. Para agregar seguridad de que proviene de *Youtube*, se le puede agregar que coincida con `youtube.be` o simplemente `youtube`, esto quizás, algún día cambie de servidor y entonces habría que cambiar la expresión regular.

```
function obtener_regex_youtube(){
    return /youtu\.?be.*?[\/=]([0-9a-z-_]{11})/i
}
```

Para no complicar las cosas, no voy a comprobar si tiene `www` o los protocolos `http` o `https`. El número 64 elevado a la potencia 11 significa que pueden haber una cantidad inimaginable de videos posibles, más de un trillón.

La función queda de la siguiente manera. Además agrego ejemplos de uso:

```js
function obtener_regex_youtube(){
 return /youtu\.?be.*?[\/=]([0-9a-z-_]{11})/i
}
function obtener_tipo_desde_enlace(url){
 var ext = "desconocido"
 var tipo = "otro"
 var regex_ext = url.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+/gi)
 if(regex_ext){
  ext = regex_ext.slice(-1)[0].slice(1)
  if( /^(mp3|mpeg)$/i.test(ext) ){ tipo = "audio" }
  if( ext=="mp4" ){ tipo = "video" }
  if( ext=="ts" ){ tipo = "video"; ext = "MP2T" }
  if( ext=="m3u" ){ tipo = "audio"; ext = "mpegURL" }
  if( ext=="m3u8" ){ tipo = "application"; ext = "x-mpegURL" }
  if(obtener_regex_youtube().test(url)){tipo="youtube"}
 }
 return tipo+"/"+ext
}

// Ejemplos de uso
[ "youtube.com?watch=0123456789a"
 , "youtu.be/0a2b4c6d8eaf"
 , "sitio.com/peli.mp4"
 , "sonido.m3u"
 , "transmite.m3u8"
 , "alarma.mp3?2"
].map(function(x){console.log("enlace: "+x+"\nmime: "+obtener_tipo_desde_enlace(x))})
```

Luego de haber puesto esa función, la función `insertar_contenido` tendría los siguientes cambios:

```
var mime = obtener_tipo_desde_enlace(url)
var tipo = mime.split("/")[0] 
var formato = mime.split("/")[1]
```

Para hacer algo diferente para cada tipo se hace mediante `if`:

```
if( tipo == "audio" ){
    ...
}
if( tipo == "video" ){
    ...
}
if( tipo == "application" ){
    ...
}
if( tipo == "youtube" ){
    ...
}
if( tipo == "otro" ){
    ...
}
```

Desafortunadamente, los `m3u8` no se pueden reproducir de manera nativa, así que es necesario usar una librería de *HLS*:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hls.js/0.12.4/hls.min.js

Se reproduce automáticamente el video al detectar la propiedad `loadedmetadata`:

```
contenido.on("loadedmetadata",function() {
    contenido.play()
})
```

El código completo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(function(){
function obtener_regex_youtube(){
 return /youtu\.?be.*?[\/=]([0-9a-z-_]{11})/i
}
function obtener_tipo_desde_enlace(url){
 var ext = "desconocido"
 var tipo = "otro"
 var regex_ext = url.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+/gi)
 if(regex_ext){
  ext = regex_ext.slice(-1)[0].slice(1)
  if( /^(mp3|mpeg)$/i.test(ext) ){ tipo = "audio" }
  if( ext=="mp4" ){ tipo = "video" }
  if( ext=="ts" ){ tipo = "video"; ext = "MP2T" }
  if( ext=="m3u" ){ tipo = "audio"; ext = "mpegURL" }
  if( ext=="m3u8" ){ tipo = "application"; ext = "x-mpegURL" }
  if(obtener_regex_youtube().test(url)){tipo="youtube"}
 }
 return tipo+"/"+ext
}
function procesar_url_youtube(url){
 var regex_youtube = obtener_regex_youtube()
 var id_video = url.match(regex_youtube)[1]
 var res = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+id_video+"?autoplay=1&controls=1"
 return res
}
function insertar_contenido(vid,elemento){

 var contenido, fuente
 var url = elemento.attr("href")

 var mime = obtener_tipo_desde_enlace(url)
 var tipo = mime.split("/")[0] 
 var formato = mime.split("/")[1]

 var cargando = $(".loading")
 function mostrar(){cargando.fadeIn(200)}
 function ocultar(){cargando.fadeOut(100)}
 mostrar()
 var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
 if(cuadro.length!=0){
  $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
 }
 if( tipo == "audio" ){
  contenido = $(document.createElement("audio"))

  contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
  contenido.attr("controls",true)
  contenido.attr("preload","auto")

  fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
  fuente.attr("src",url)
  fuente.attr("type",mime)

  contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
  contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
  contenido.append(fuente)
 }
 if( tipo == "video" ){
  contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))

  contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
  contenido.attr("controls",true)
  contenido.attr("preload","auto")

  fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
  fuente.attr("src",url)
  fuente.attr("type",mime)

  contenido.attr("width","100%")
  contenido.attr("height","100%")

  contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
  contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
  contenido.append(fuente)
 }
 if( tipo == "application" ){

  contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))

  contenido.attr("autoplay",true)
  contenido.attr("controls",true)
  contenido.attr("preload","metadata")

  fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
  fuente.attr("src",url)
  fuente.attr("type",mime)

  contenido.attr("width","100%")
  contenido.attr("height","100%")

  contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
  contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)

  contenido.on("loadedmetadata",function() {
   contenido.play()
  })

  contenido.append(fuente)

 }
 if( tipo == "youtube" ){
  contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))

  contenido.attr("width","100%")
  contenido.attr("height","100%")

  contenido.attr("src", procesar_url_youtube(url) )
  contenido.on('load', ocultar)
 }
 if( tipo == "otro" ){
  var id = elemento.attr("id")
  if(id==undefined){
   contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))

   contenido.attr("width","100%")
   contenido.attr("height","100%")

   contenido.attr("src",url)
   contenido.on('load', ocultar)
  } else {
   contenido = $(document.createElement("div"))
   contenido.append($("#c_"+id))
   ocultar()
  }
 }
 vid.html("")
 vid.append(contenido)
 $("#enlaces a").removeClass("playing")
 elemento.addClass("playing")
}
function principal(){
 var indice = 0
 var vid = $('#myvid')
 var primer_elemento = $("#enlaces a:first")
 var enlaces = $("#enlaces a").map((x, y) => {
  return {
   a: x,
   b: y
  }
 })

 insertar_contenido(vid, primer_elemento)
 primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

 $("#enlaces a.link").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  indice = enlaces.filter((x, y) => y.b == this)[0].a
  insertar_contenido(vid, esto)
 })

 $("#atras").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  --indice
  if (indice < 0) {
   indice += enlaces.length
  }
  enlaces[indice].b.click()
 })

 $("#siguiente").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var esto = $(this)
  ++indice
  if (indice >= enlaces.length) {
   indice -= enlaces.length
  }
  enlaces[indice].b.click()
 })
}

principal()

})
```

```css
#myvid {
  color: #ffff;
}

.container * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container *::after,
.container *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #A97A7A;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  background: #010101;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
}

.vidcontainer {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.vids {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #292626;
  max-height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #616060;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  list-style: none;
  direction: rtl;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #8A8A8A;
  border: 1px solid #AFACAC;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #FF8D00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vids a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* --- controllers --- */

.controllers {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #777;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
  border-color: #ff8d00;
  color: #ff8d00;
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay::after {
  content: "\f04b";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.paused::after {
  content: "\f04c";
}

.sound::after {
  content: "\f027";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.sound2:after {
  content: "\f028";
}

.muted::after {
  content: "\f026";
}

.btnFS::after {
  content: "\f065";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.ads {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #777;
  top: 27.5px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.bigplay {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 127.5px;
  left: 85px;
  z-index: 11;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}

.closeme {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px!important;
  color: #ff8d00;
  font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

.playing:after {
  content: "\f01d";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #ff8d00;
  float: left;
}


/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Progress bar */

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #999;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: #eee;
}


/* time and duration */

.time {
  width: 12%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  right: -12%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.topControl:hover .progress {
  width: 88%;
  height: 12px;
}


/* VOLUME BAR CSS
        volume bar */

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff8d00;
  z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
  top: 172.5px;
  left: 330px;
  position: absolute;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}

ul.speedcnt {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'verdana', tahoma, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}

#c_inline-1 h3, #c_inline-1 p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hls.js/0.12.4/hls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="vidcontainer">
  <div id="myvid"></div>
  <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="videolist">
  <nav class="vids">
      <a id="atras" href="#">Back</a>
      <a id="siguiente" href="#">Next</a>
  </nav>
  <nav id="enlaces" class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8">test1 m3u8</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4"> test2 mp4</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://cdn.trancearoundtheworld.co.uk/files/tatw-301.6.mp3">test3 mp3</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH50zuS8DD0">test3 YouTube</a>
      <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d387144.0075834208!2d-73.97800349999999!3d40.7056308!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew+York%2C+NY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1394298866288">test4 iFrame WebSite</a>
      <a class="link" href="#" id="link_1">test5 Inline Only Text (tags html)</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">
      <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_1">
          <h3>Loren Title</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vis dicant essent mandamus te, et pri sale perfecto definitionem. Te doming epicurei maiestatis ius, omnis mucius disputationi ex eam, tempor diceret vulputate in nam. Ut maluisset mnesarchum mel, et affert offendit eum. At vim feugiat dolorum temporibus, ei nusquam placerat oporteat per. Has te alia definitionem, has ocurreret maluisset eu, sea et mucius essent philosophia.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo una pregunta y, dentro del `if(es_video){}` se agregaba el tipo de formato del vídeo mediante esto, tenia yo: `fuente.attr("type","video/"+formato)` entonces quedaría de esta manera: `fuente.attr("type",tipo+formato)` o no. Gracias por responder :)

Comment: @Lou Tendría que ser `fuente.attr("type",tipo+"/"+formato)`, o mejor, `fuente.attr("type",ext)`

Comment: @Lou Hice una edición en la respuesta, cambiando la expresión regular. y algo en los `if`.

Comment: si el problema es youtube por reproducir videos, deberias de enviar [algunas cabeceras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526965/5695795)  de parte del servidor para evitar el problema de CORS mira mas en la web de [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: @Lou Listo, edité la respuesta, los _HLS_ funcionan mediante una librería adicional.

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias amigo :)

Comment: @Eslacuare Amigo estoy usando este ejemplo que has aportado, pero no funciona para `HLS` videos `ts` y, `m3u8` incluso veo que YouTube tampoco funciona. ¿Por qué no funciona amigo?

Comment: @Eslacuare Ya intente cambiando las rutas de los archivos ya que algunos no existen, pero tampoco :/

Comment: @Valentina Cualquier problema que tengas ven aquí y hablamos... https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105207/c Si me dejas un mensaje ahí lo leeré en cuanto pueda, no estoy todo el tiempo conectado.