# Autoplay en Youtube Embed no funciona en moviles

Tags: html5, programación-móvil, responsive, youtube, youtube-api

por más que leo las referencias de Youtube no logro hacer que la función autoplay de un video insertado funcione en móviles, en escritorio no tengo problema

```
<div class="video-responsive">
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-JWDnSVK0rQ?controls=0&autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&&playlist=-JWDnSVK0rQ&mute=1"></iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Agregue la opción mute junto a la de autoplay y el problema persiste

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no te funciona? ¿Se ve el vídeo en blanco o simplemente tienes que seguir dándole al *play* para que arranque?

Comment: Tengo que darle play para arrancar, el autoplay no funciona y solo es en móviles en escritorio me va genial

Comment: ¿Estás usando un dispositivo IOS o uno Android para las pruebas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Android para hacer las pruebas y el inspector de elementos de Google para redimensionar en ambos casos el autoplay sigue sin funcionar

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

Comment: estimado, te comparto la respuesta ubicada en la pregunta citada anteriormente https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/195693/118752